# How can I host TCP Listener in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, azure-cloud-services, tcplistener

We have an azure cloud service that is listening on TCP port for incoming binary data. The service is also responsible for sending an acknowledge packet to the client devices. Now we have to move this service to AWS but I couldn't find any suitable solution. I look at the WebSocket in AWS, but WebSocket requires a specific JSON format instead of binary data. Which path could we take to solve this situation?

Comment: It is difficult to provide an answer without more details.  The simplest solution would be to run your service on EC2 with a public IP address, or else put it behind a Network Load Balancer configured with a TCP listener that delegates to your service.  But without more details it is impossible to provide a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using the AWS ECS service. I created a docker image of TCP listener and published it to AWS ECS with a network load balancer.

Comment: How is it working till now? I also wanted to host a tcplistener online which currently is an console application built with c# running locally.

Comment: @karanugale last time I checked, it was working fine.